# Cause <DIV> contents to spread out?

Tags: html, css

Imagine I have a navigation bar in my page header, with a number of links. I'd like the links to spread out horizontally to fill the parent ; is there a way to do this using CSS which doesn't rely on me hard-coding based on the number of links? e.g if I add or remove a link I'd like it to still work.

I tried:

```
<div class="navBar">
    <a class="navBtn" href="#" >Home</a>
    <a class="navBtn" href="#" >Services</a>
    <a class="navBtn" href="#" >About us</a>
    <a class="navBtn" href="#" >Blog</a>
    <a class="navBtn" href="#" >Contact</a>
</div>

div.navBar
{
    text-align:justify;
}
a.navBtn
{
    font-style:italic;
}
```

But this just left-aligns the text. I know I could use a table but just to show I can, I'm trying to do it 'properly'. Or, is this a case where a table is 'proper'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text-align: justified;

Comment: I hadn't seen this before, so I googled around a bit.  There's a lot of commentary saying <code>Text-align: justified;</code> is unreliable.  Have you found a way to make it work reliably, or a context in which it works well enough?

Comment: Try it - most newer versions of browsers are good at supporting this. The other option I listed works with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a table with width: 100% around your nav bar and have each nav item be in a td
you could even set the width, in percentage, of each td